# Not able to run xboard

Tags: 16.04, games

I am running ubuntu 16.04
I installed xboard using the command

```
   sudo apt-get install xboard
```

When I launch Xboard, I can see the icon (knight) in the Launcher but no chess board is displayed.  If I click on the icon in the launcher, it causes xboard to quit.

I did a "purge" and then installed again but the results were the same.

Comment: What happens if you just run `xboard` in a terminal? If the program exits with an error, it should show that error in the terminal then and knowing that would help us fix the problem.

Comment: Ran xboard from terminal, it exited with message -whitePieceColor not defined

Answer (score 0):

The xboard was installed without default values for some of the options.
The xboard file .xboardrc, in home directory, defines values for various options. Set the following options:

```
-whitePieceColor                #FFFF20
-blackPieceColor                #202020
-lightSquareColor               #C8C3C5
-darkSquareColor                #77A26D
-highlightSquareColor           #FFFF00 
-premoveHighlightColor          #FF0000
```

This solved the problem.